# How to find similar tag cominations from single table?

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

I have a table like below

```
=====================
item|   flavor
====+================
111 |   amaretto
111 |   blueberry
222 |   amaretto
333 |   blueberry
333 |   chocolate
444 |   chocolate
444 |   amaretto
555 |   chocolate
666 |   blueberry
666 |   amaretto
666 |   chocolate
777 |   pastry
777 |   blueberry
777 |   amaretto
777 |   chocolate
888 |   amaretto
888 |   chocolate
999 |   chocolate
999 |   blueberry
999 |   amaretto
101 |   amaretto
101 |   blueberry
=====================
```

The column `item` indicates name of ice cream and the `flavor` column shows the flavor combination contained in it. I want my db to return me alternate ice creams in case if I dont have one required. For example, if I am looking item 111, I want `111` and `101`, which has exact same flavor combination. I have a query like;

```
SELECT item
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY item
HAVING SUM(tag = 'amaretto') > 0
   AND SUM(tag = 'blueberry ') > 0
```

But it returns a result like;

```
111
666
777
999
101
```

This is because all these records have `amaretto` and `blueberry` in them. But for `666`, `777` and `999`, there are additional flavors in them. I dont want to display them. Instead, I just want `111` ad `101`. Is there any way to achieve this? Do I need additional tables / can I achieve this using my current schema? I use PHP + MySQL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT item
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY item
HAVING SUM(tag = 'amaretto') > 0
   AND SUM(tag = 'blueberry ') > 0
   and sum(tag not in ('amaretto','blueberry ')) = 0
```

I.e. add `sum(tag not in ('amaretto','blueberry ')) = 0` to make sure no other flavors are included.

Answer (score 0):

With the aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT you get the flavor list per item. You can then look for duplicate lists and show the associated item list.

```
select flavors, group_concat(item order by item) as items
from
(
  select item, group_concat(tag order by tag) as flavors
  from mytable
  group by item
) items_with_flavorlist
group by flavors
having count(*) > 1;
```